# How can I get the value of a cell in a DATAGRID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Trying to get a Cell value from my DATAGRID using ASP.NET C# and I get error message saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here is what I have:

```
foreach (DataGridItem dgItem in dgPrintTicket.Items)
{
    string itm = dgItem.Cells[1].FindControl("Item_Number").ToString();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error make your code null safe:

```
foreach (DataGridItem dgItem in dgPrintTicket.Items)
{
    var control = dgItem.Cells[1].FindControl("Item_Number");

    string itm = control != null ? control.ToString() : null;
}
```

But I suppose you should try to get the value of the cell by following code:

```
foreach (DataGridItem dgItem in dgPrintTicket.Items)
{
    string itm = dgItem.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

If there really is a control found by FindControl use this code fragment:

```
foreach (DataGridItem dgItem in dgPrintTicket.Items)
{
    var control = dgItem.Cells[1].FindControl("Item_Number") as Label;

    string itm = control != null ? control.Text : null;
}
```

Comment: ok that fixed the error, but I can't get the value from either solution you stated. When I debug the first solution I can see the value in the "control" variable, but when I assign it to "itm" then the value shows as "System.Web.UI.WefControls.Label" instead of the actual value. Why?

Comment: The control.ToString() method shows as default the type of the control. In your case this is "System.Web.UI.WefControls.Label". Probably you find your value in the control.Text property, assuming the label contains your value. What other controls are in this cells?

Comment: tried control.Text, but the "Text" option doesn't show or come up as an option. I can only use control.ToString(). Its a Label control that I added in the DataGrid in ItemTemplates. When I debug and place my cursor over the "control" var it says control = "Text = F2140          " so its finding the control and the value, just can't extract it for some odd reason.

Comment: Sorry, missed the type cast to "System.Web.UI.WefControls.Label". Fixed this in variant 3.

Comment: I have another question that I posted but got no response to. Its been 2 days wondering if you can help with it. In this same DataGrid one of the columns is a DropDownList and the other three are just labels. When I bind my DataGrid to my DataTable the DropDownList stays empty. Nothing getting binded to it. You have any Idea what I can be?

Answer (score 1):

dgItem.Cells[1].FindControl("Item_Number") is null, ToString() is trying to convert a null objecdt to string which fails. You need to ensure that A) there are at least 2 columns in the data grid and B) FindControl("Item_Number") will actually return something.

Comment: Yes there are 4 columns and the second column is "Item_Number". The DataGrid has 3 rows of data so not sure whats happening.